# Action on touching color

Tags: java

I made a flappy birds game and is working well till now. But now I am stuck with a problem, I want the game to start all over when the the bird touches the color of the wall. Here is the source code. By the way, I think this may not be properly formatted. As I am a newbie, can you also suggest how to formath this code properly? Thank you.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class FlappyBirds extends JPanel implements ActionListener,KeyListener {

    public int WIDTH=800,HEIGHT=800,x=WIDTH/2-10,y=HEIGHT/2-10 , gravity=0,       ticks=0;
    public static FlappyBirds flappy;
    public boolean jump;
    public boolean run=true;
    public ArrayList<Rectangle>walls;

    public Random generator;

    public FlappyBirds(){
        Timer t=new Timer(10,this);
        JFrame window=new JFrame("Flappy Birds");
        window.setSize(WIDTH ,HEIGHT);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.add(this);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.addKeyListener(this);
        walls=new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

        generator=new Random();
        addWall(true);
        addWall(true);


        t.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        flappy=new FlappyBirds();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(new Color(0,200,255));
        g.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.fillRect(0, HEIGHT-100, WIDTH,100);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(0,HEIGHT-110,WIDTH,10);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 15, 15);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial",15,15));

        int colorman=0;
        g.setColor(new Color(200,200,40));

        for(Rectangle rect:walls){
            paintWall(rect,g);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        while(run==true){
            repaint();

            ticks ++;
            if(jump){
                if(ticks%8==0){
                    gravity=-10;
                }
            } 
            else if(ticks%8==0 && gravity<15 && jump==false){
                gravity+=2;

            }
            y += gravity; 

            for(Rectangle rect:walls){
                rect.x -=10;

            }
            for(int i=0;i<walls.size();i++){
                Rectangle r=walls.get(i);

                if(r.x+r.width<0){
                    walls.remove(r);


                    addWall(false);     

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider posting an [MCVE]

Comment: I can't get you, Can you explain a bit further?

Comment: Read the link [MCVE] : you need to post a code that can be compiled and run, and should be the minimal one to demonstrate the problem.